# How RAM is used on CGI query?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, ram

The user sends a file via HTML form 
CGI script, installed on the server, receives the file and, say, writes it down to the disk. As simple as only possible.
As I understand, files, sent to the server via POST, are stored in the RAM on the Server, before they are written on the disk. (If I am not right - please, correct me).
The question is IF the file, that a user sends, weights 2GB and the server (just for example) has only 1 GB of RAM on board? What will happen then?
thanks!

Comment: memory paging to disk

Comment: @Sobrique Thank you!

Comment: The whole reason CGI.pm writes the file to disk is to avoid eating up lots of RAM, so the claim that the entire file is stored in RAM before being written to disk seems like completely nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole reason CGI.pm writes the file to disk is to avoid eating up lots of RAM, so the claim that the entire file is stored in RAM before being written to disk makes no sense.

CGI.pm writes it to disk as it reads it from the pipe from apache.

Comment: Thanks. Ikegami, can you tell, if I have that file received by CGI script and then, before writing it down to a disk, I have to process it (say, put it into array, split by small cuts of the data, and manipulate this array and only after write it to the disk. What then will happen? During that manipulations which memory will be used?

Comment: Yes, arrays exist in memory.

Comment: is there a chance to cope with it? I mean, is there a chance to have the array on disk in any way without losses of speed? I tried DBM::Deep but it takes hours for the  mentioned operation... on MacBook Pro i7 2.8Ghz 2014.... It is horrible.. Is there any other solutions? What do you think about PDL? Is it worth to try?

Comment: Re "is there a chance to have the array on disk in any way without losses of speed?", That makes no sense. As I've previously said, arrays exist in memory. As for an efficient way of doing what you want to do... Well, that would depend on what you want to do.